# Error while writing data to a file in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

in my application, i have placed an empty

1. myFile.txt

when i have internet connection , i get json data from internet and save the json string in it with following code

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType:@"txt"];
[myString writeToFile:filePath automatically:YES encoding:NSUTF... error:nil];

//now while retrieving it when no internet connection
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF..  error:nil];
```

now myString returns with `@""`... why i am not been able to write data?

Best Regards

Comment: Which language you are using? This cant be Obj-c !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you want to do is not possible (or at least strongly discouraged) to update files in the app bundle.

If you’re downloading files and want to store them on the device you should use the Documents directory. You can get the path to this directory with:

```
- (NSString *)getDocumentsDirectory {  
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
    return [paths objectAtIndex:0];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First check weather the contents are getting written to file. You can view the file in xcode.
What i suggest is when you run the app create this empty file. Then you can Read and write to that file easily.

Try Using Below code:

```
 NSError* error = nil;
 NSString* jsonFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myfile"];
 NSString* jsonPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:jsonFileName    
    ofType:@"txt"];
 NSString* jsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:jsonPath 
          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Documents directory:

Write to file

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
        (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    //make a file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/textfile.txt", 
                                                  documentsDirectory];
    //create content - four lines of text
    NSString *content = @"One\nTwo\nThree\nFour\nFive";
    //save content to the documents directory
    [content writeToFile:fileName 
                     atomically:NO 
                           encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy 
                                  error:nil];
```

Display content:

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
                    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    //make a file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/textfile.txt", 
                                                  documentsDirectory];
    NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName
                                                  usedEncoding:nil
                                                         error:nil];
```